# CSS Grid Show items on at twice

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

please, I have a small problem with my **CSS Grid** positioning. I have four columns with `auto-fit` property. No problem if I have monitor bigger than 1376px in width for example (also not problem in mobile devices because then I'm showing only one item per row - different pixel ration as you know). But I have problem with monitor which has 1024px width e.g. Then I show 3 items and in second row I have just last one item which is looking very bad.

HML Snippet

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="grid-box"> 
        <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-hands-wash"></i></div>
        <h2>Wash your hands</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-head-side-mask"></i></div>
        <h2>Cover your face</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-people-arrows"></i></div>
        <h2>Social distance</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-spray-can"></i></div>
        <h2>Sanitize common items</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css snippet

```css
.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr) );
    min-height: calc(50vh - 20pt);
}

.grid-box {
    margin: 10pt;
    padding: 20pt 10pt 0pt 20pt;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba($color: #ccddcc, $alpha: 0.6);
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

My desired result is show it only in as twins. Not 3 items in first column and last in second. Only all 4 items in one row or if monitor is smaller than 2 items on first row and 2 items on second row.

It is possible please without using `media-query` in **css**? Yes. I know that it's possible via `media-query` but I believe that CSS Grid is smart to solve it without using this. Thanks.

Comment: use mediaqueries, that's what they are here for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group two `grid-box` together inside another `div` and get the desired output. 
`

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="grid-box"> 
            <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-hands-wash"></i></div>
            <h2>Wash your hands</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-box">
            <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-head-side-mask"></i></div>
            <h2>Cover your face</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="grid-box">
            <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-people-arrows"></i></div>
            <h2>Social distance</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-box">
            <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-spray-can"></i></div>
            <h2>Sanitize common items</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Also works great and without edit CSS. Thank you very much. Oh yes, splitting :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put each two divs in one, like this : https://codepen.io/Aypro18/pen/OJyMVMq?editors=1100

**CSS:**

```
.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr) );
    min-height: calc(50vh - 20pt);

}

.grid-container{
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr) );
    min-height: calc(50vh - 20pt);
}

.grid-box {
    margin: 10pt;
    padding: 20pt 10pt 0pt 20pt;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba($color: #ccddcc, $alpha: 0.6);
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 0 34%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-box"> 
        <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-hands-wash"></i></div>
        <h2>Wash your hands</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-head-side-mask"></i></div>
        <h2>Cover your face</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-people-arrows"></i></div>
        <h2>Social distance</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-spray-can"></i></div>
        <h2>Sanitize common items</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex without mediaquerie could also be an option here , since no elements are to be spanning a row or a column.

example of the idea that will wrap elements in 1, 2 or 4 lines:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid-box {
  margin: 10pt;
  padding: 20pt 10pt 0pt 20pt;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(204, 221, 204, .6);
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 350px;
  min-height: calc(50vh - 40pt);
}

.grid-box {/* optionnal, for the demo */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="content">
  <div class="grid-box">
    <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-hands-wash"></i></div>
    <h2>Wash your hands</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-box">
    <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-head-side-mask"></i></div>
    <h2>Cover your face</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-box">
    <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-people-arrows"></i></div>
    <h2>Social distance</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-box">
    <div class="grid-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-spray-can"></i></div>
    <h2>Sanitize common items</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```